# Workaround for Ampersand in SWT Table Header

Tags: java, windows, swt

An ampersand in an SWT Table header will not be displayed, is there a known workaround?

I have to display an ampersand in my application and i'm looking for a workaround...

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=154904

if you don't want to read the full atricle just follow this example

```
public class TableWidget {

  Display d;

  Shell s;

  TableWidget() {
    d = new Display();
    s = new Shell(d);

    s.setSize(250, 200);

    s.setText("A Table Shell Example");
    s.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Table t = new Table(s, SWT.BORDER);

    TableColumn tc1 = new TableColumn(t, SWT.CENTER);
    TableColumn tc2 = new TableColumn(t, SWT.CENTER);
    TableColumn tc3 = new TableColumn(t, SWT.CENTER);
    tc1.setText("First&&Name"); //THESE ampersands won't be shown
    tc2.setText("Last & Name"); //and HERE
    tc3.setText("Address");
    tc1.setWidth(70);
    tc2.setWidth(70);
    tc3.setWidth(80);
    t.setHeaderVisible(true);

    TableItem item1 = new TableItem(t, SWT.NONE);
    item1.setText(new String[] { "Tim", "Hatton", "Kentucky" });
    TableItem item2 = new TableItem(t, SWT.NONE);
    item2.setText(new String[] { "Caitlyn", "Warner", "Ohio" });
    TableItem item3 = new TableItem(t, SWT.NONE);
    item3.setText(new String[] { "Reese", "Miller", "Ohio" });

    s.open();
    while (!s.isDisposed()) {
      if (!d.readAndDispatch())
        d.sleep();
    }
    d.dispose();
  }

  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    new TableWidget();
  }

}
```

and yes, of course '\u0026' won't work as well - i'm not really expecting a solution but maybe someone is smarter than i am...

Comment: So, what's the problem with using `&&` instead of just `&` then? Works fine for me. Or is this specific to a certain version of Windows/SWT?

Comment: You only have to use SWT version >= 3.7.2 to get rid of this bug!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, right later Version might solve the problem, but we have 'oldfashioned' customers, we even produce code for java 1.6 using eclipse 3.4 (!!)

but i found a WORKAROUND as requested using an symbol that looks exactly like the one i request.... if you replace any ampersands (\u0026) with fullwidth ampersand (\uFF06) you get rid of that problem....

i found the solution on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampersand, where they displayed alternative ampersand!

i'm sorry that i created such a mess here! thanks for your support...